# Can I still use Profane Memento if I have out Silent Gravestone?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I use abilities of [Profane Memento](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProfane%20Memento%5d) if I have out [Silent Gravestone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSilent%20Gravestone%5d) ?

Answer (score 13):

Silent Gravestone has no interaction with Profane Memento. Silent Gravestone's static ability says

> Cards in graveyards can't be the targets of spells or abilities.

Profane Memento's ability does not try to target anything in graveyards or otherwise. It simply reacts to cards moving into the graveyard. So, the ability keeps working even if you have Silent Gravestone on the battlefield.

Comment: I'm glad you found their reply helpful! This place is great for questions about Magic, and other board games. Please note though that comments are generally not the place to say thank you. That's done by upvoting their answer on the left, and clicking the check mark beneath the upvote to mark it as accepted. This gives murgatroid99 some points for their answer, and notifies everyone that you found this answer satisfactory! (And also gives you a few bonus points.)